# Not able to override pluggable function with a mu_plugin

Tags: email, html-email

I'm trying to modify the email that's sent to users when they are invited to join my multisite network. Understanding I can only use the pluggable function, how do I override the default email with a must use plugin? Right now it's not allowing me to override and shows the default text.

Here's my current code:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
        $siteUrl = get_site_url().'/login';
        $email_subject = "Welcome to Dewsly ".$user_login;

        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), $email_subject, $message);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;

        ob_start();

        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>
            <body style="background:#e5f6fb">

            </body>
        </html>

        <?php

        $message = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        wp_mail($user_email, $email_subject, $message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function isn't for MS signups, the `wpmu_signup_user_notification` function in `wp-includes/ms-functions.php` handles that. here's the docblock from that function:

```
/**
 * Notify user of signup success.
 *
 * This is the notification function used when no new site has
 * been requested.
 *
 * Filter 'wpmu_signup_user_notification' to bypass this function or
 * replace it with your own notification behavior.
 *
 * Filter 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email' and
 * 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject' to change the content
 * and subject line of the email sent to newly registered users.
 *
```

Comment: What would that filter look like? I've got this and it's not working: function change_activation_subject( $user_id ) {
  $user = new WP_User($user_id);
  $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
  $email_subject = "Welcome to Dewsly ".$user_login;
  return $subject;
 }
 add_filter( "wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject", "change_activation_subject" );

Comment: I haven't tried the filter out, I don't have a MS setup at the moment. Did you get it to work? I can give it a shot later today if you still need help.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get it running yet. Not sure why, but I can't get it to filter those at all. It seems to always access the default unless it's been updated in the Multisite Settings.